# Is there a faster alternative to target.value = me.textbox.value?

Tags: vba, performance, excel

I have an Excel UserForm that has about 15 fields (text boxes and drop down lists) and copies the data to a sheet when a button is pressed. it has about a 15 min run time and after stepping through the only lines that took a noticeable amount of time were

```
With ws
  .Unprotect Password:="password" 
  .Cells(iRow, 1).Value = Me.Textbox1.Value
  .Cells(iRow, 1).Value = Me.time.Value
  .Cells(iRow, 2).Value = Me.card.Value 
  .Cells(iRow, 1).Value = Me.nature.Value
  .Cells(iRow, 2).Value = Me.ma.Value
  .Cells(iRow, 1).Value = Me.mem1.Value
  .Cells(iRow, 2).Value = Me.mem2.Value
  .Cells(iRow, 3).Value = Me.mem3.Value
  .Cells(iRow, 4).Value = Me.mem4.Value
  .Cells(iRow, 5).Value = Me.mem5.Value
  .Cells(iRow, 6).Value = Me.mem6.Value
  .Cells(iRow, 7).Value = Me.mem7.Value
  .Cells(iRow, 8).Value = Me.mem8.Value
  .Cells(iRow, 9).Value = Me.mem9.Value
  .Cells(iRow, 10).Value = Me.mem10.Value
  .Protect Password:="password"
End With
```

each of the copying lines took about 1 minute to run. I read that using Value2 is faster but it didn't make any noticeable difference.

No other code runs during this and I disabled auto-updates on the functions in cells.

Comment: `I disabled auto-updates on the functions in cells` - do you mean you switched calculation mode to manual?

Comment: You appear to be overwriting cells, to begin with.

Comment: Do you have worksheet/workbook event procedures active ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Any time you can make a single write to the worksheet in place of multiple writes you should see increased performance, so using an array instead of going cell-by-cell will likely improve things:

```
With ws
  .Unprotect Password:="password" 

  .Cells(iRow, 1).Resize(1,10).Value = _
      Array(Me.mem1.Value, Me.mem2.Value, _
            Me.mem3.Value, Me.mem4.Value, _
            Me.mem5.Value, Me.mem6.Value, _
            Me.mem7.Value, Me.mem8.Value, _
            Me.mem9.Value, Me.mem10.Value)

  .Protect Password:="password"
End With
```